# How can I access the arguments of a function in a decorator for that function?

Tags: r, decorator

I want to write a decorator to easily print the type of all arguments that were given to a function in R.

So far I managed to write code that does that for me, but I want to avoid copy-pasting it to the required functions.

```
    fun <- function(...){
        c = as.list(match.call())
        d= lapply(c, print(typeof))
        print(d)}
```

This prints the expected result.
Now i wanna embed this behaviour in a decorator, but I can't access the arguments of the function within the decorator.

```
    print_arguments <- function(f){
        function(...){
        arguments_of_f = ???
        d= lapply(arguments_of_f, print(typeof))
        print(d)
        return(f(...))
        }
    }
```

How do I get the arguments of f in this case?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Not completely sure why you are using `match.call`. The easiest way get the arguments is to use `list(...)`. This you can also use in your decorator:

```
print_arguments <- function(f){
  function(...){
    d <- sapply(list(...), typeof)
    print(d)
    return(f(...))
  }
}
```

I am using `sapply` instead of `lapply` as the output can easily be converted to a vector and this gives a cleaner output.

Output:

```
> foo <- print_arguments(plot)
> foo(iris, pch = 20)
              pch 
  "list" "double"
```

**Note**

As remarked by @MrFlick, this does not work when the decorated function uses non-standard argument evaluation. For example:

```
> subset_deco <- print_arguments(subset)
> subset_deco(iris, Sepal.Length > 1)
 Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

Comment: This would cause a bit of trouble if the function relies on non-standard evaluation. For example `subset(mtcars, cyl==6)` works just fine but `foo <- print_arguments(subset); foo(mtcars, cyl==6)` would not.

Comment: I used match.call since it was the first way I found to get the arguments of a function. Is it correct that the "..." is the short way of getting the arguments of the function it occurs in? I cant find any documentation and have no idea how to look for it. 
And thanks for your answer! I will try it out later today.

Comment: @MrFlick You are right. To get that working would be quite a challenge; I don't really see a solution. I'll think about it and in the mean time add a warning to my answer.

Comment: The solution doesn't seem to work for me. The Testfunction i use is 
fun <- function(a=4,b=6){return(a+b)},
but the result is:
```
   function(...){
            arguments_of_f <- sapply(list(...), typeof)
            print(arguments_of_f)
            return(f(...))
        }
    <environment: 0x92b3578>
```